# Exception is appearing when persisting already persisted entity?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities- `User`, `UserPayment`.`User` and `UserPayment` have a `OneToMany` relation. There is a variable `setDefault` in `UserPayment`. When new `UserPayment`, its `setDefault` should be set `true` and other `UserPayment` of that particular `User` should be set to `false`. After new `UserPayment` is created, when persisting, I get the below error.

Entity User

```
@Entity
public class User  {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Id",nullable = false,updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UserPayment> userPaymentList;
        
}
```

Entity UserPayment

```
@Entity
public class UserPayment{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private boolean defaultPayment;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity addNewCardDetail(@RequestBody UserPayment userPayment,Principal principal) {  
    if(principal != null) {
        String username = principal.getName();
        User user = userServiceImpl.findUserByUsername(username);
        userServiceImpl.uodateUserBilling(user,userPayment);
        return new ResponseEntity("Your card has been successfully saved",HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity("Card not saved",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Service implementation

```
@Override
public void uodateUserBilling(User user, UserPayment userPayment) {
    userPayment.setDefaultPayment(true);
    userPayment.setUser(user);
    List<UserPayment> paymentList = user.getUserPaymentList();
    for(UserPayment eachPaymnet:paymentList) {
        eachPaymnet.setDefaultPayment(false);
        paymentRepository.save(eachPaymnet);
    }    
    user.getUserPaymentList().add(userPayment);
    userRepository.save(user); 
    
}
```

Error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple representations of the same entity [com.bookstore.domain.UserPayment#53] are being merged. Detached: [com.bookstore.domain.UserPayment@6ea664ae]; Managed: [com.bookstore.domain.UserPayment@790e8792]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [com.bookstore.domain.UserPayment#53] are being merged. Detached: [com.bookstore.domain.UserPayment@6ea664ae]; Managed: [com.bookstore.domain.UserPayment@790e8792]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
```

Comment: Do not save UserPayment using separate repository, just add userPayment object in user.userPaymentList and then save user using userRepository.

Comment: @ChintanRadia I stilled got the error after removing `paymentRepository.save(eachPaymnet);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring in the `uodateUserBilling()`,because when persisting already persisted  `UserPayment` you are again adding it to the list `user.getUserPaymentList().add(userPayment);`.Add `UserPayment` to the list only if its a new entry else dont add it.Try the below code

```
    public void updateUserPayment(User user, UserPayment userPayment) {
    userPayment.setUser(user);
    List<UserPayment> paymentList = user.getUserPaymentList();
  
    if(userPayment.getId() != null ) {
        paymentRepository.save(userPayment);
    }
    else{
        userPayment.setDefaultPayment(true);
        for(UserPayment eachPaymnet:paymentList) {
                eachPaymnet.setDefaultPayment(false);
        }    
        user.getUserPaymentList().add(userPayment);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct your `uodateUserBilling` in the following way:

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public void uodateUserBilling(User user, UserPayment userPayment) {
    userPayment.setDefaultPayment(true);
    List<UserPayment> paymentList = user.getUserPaymentList();
    for(UserPayment eachPaymnet:paymentList) {
        eachPaymnet.setDefaultPayment(false);
    }    
    user.getUserPaymentList().add(userPayment);
    userPayment.setUser(user);
    userRepository.save(user); 
    
}
```

Comment: i tried this,but i still got the same error

Comment: Try else to put  `@Transactional` on `addNewCardDetail` instead of `uodateUserBilling`

Comment: Tried this as well but still got the same error

Comment: Could you please show `UserPayment` object that you try to save. Is this object have  `id`?